# Determine Non-Matching Item in Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables similar to this:

```
#1
OriginalID | Area
========== | ====
2          | Abdomen
3          | Abdomen

#2
Area   | Part
====   | ====
Abdomen| Abdomen
Bottom | Bottom


#3
Part   | OriginalID
====   | ==========
Abdomen| 2
Bottom | 3
```

**Desired result**:

```
OriginalID | Area    | Part
========== | ====    | ====
3          | Abdomen | NULL
```

Once I figure out the above I can update the table to:

```
#3
Part   | OriginalID
====   | ==========
Abdomen| 2
Bottom | 3
Abdomen| 3
```

So, for desired result I would like to know that it originally was assigned to 50 (table `#1`) but there is no corresponding relationship for that specific `Area` in table `#3`.

Now, I would like to find if an `Area` in `#1` is not associated to the same `ID` in `#3`. `#3` is the many to many relationship between `ID` and `Part`. `Area` has been spun out into its own table now. But it has been kept in `#1`. Unfortunately, it was still being used and now that I am refactoring some code to be correct the relationship in `#1` with `Area` hasn't been properly ported to `#2`.

`#2` Is the many-to-many relationship between `Area` and `Part`.

Is there a way find which `Area` relationship hasn't been accounted for in `#3` with SQL? It would be nice to have the computer do it for me but I can't quite wrap my head around how this would be done.

Thanks in advance!

**Here's Some Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #1
(
    OriginalID INT NOT NULL,
    Area VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #2
(
    Area VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Part VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #3
(
    Part VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    OriginalID INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #1 VALUES
    (2, 'Abdomen'),
    (3, 'Abdomen')

INSERT INTO #2 VALUES
    ('Abdomen', 'Abdomen'),
    ('Bottom', 'Bottom')

INSERT INTO #3 VALUES
    ('Abdomen', 2),
    ('Bottom', 3)

DROP TABLE #1
DROP TABLE #2
DROP TABLE #3
```

**Jason's response is currently incorrect**

```
SELECT a.Area
FROM #1 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM #2 as b 
  INNER JOIN #3 as c 
  ON b.Part = c.Part
  WHERE a.Area = b.Area)
```

Results in `NULL` result.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: So you want to show the rows from #1 where they don't exist in #3?

Comment: @GordonLinoff OK, I added more detail.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, Yes, that is what I would like.

Comment: Where are you getting `50` from?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I'm just showing that the data keeps going on and on. I could update it so it is more realistic of the problem to test against, sorry.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Now it is showing "real" data that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will give you which are not in #3:

```
SELECT a.originalID, b.part 
from #1 a
join #2 b
on a.area = b.area
where not exists (select * from #3 c where c.originalID = a.originalID and c.part = b.part)
```

Comment: This is actually resulting in extra data. But it did what I asked for, so I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.Area
FROM table1 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM table2 as b 
INNER JOIN table3 as c 
ON table2.part = table3.part
WHERE a.Area = b.Area)
```

Comment: I tried yours and it just comes up blank. I'll put the code up in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, see if this helps.

```
Select table1.OriginalID, table1.Area, table3.Part
From table1
Left Join table3 on table1.OriginalID = table3.OriginalID
Where table3.OriginalID is null
```

Comment: This tells me which `Area`s aren't called in `table3`. But if there is an item in `table1` but doesn't have the corresponding match of the specific `Area` in `table3` it doesn't show up. If that makes any sense :-)

Comment: I updated the example to show what I meant with actual code that fails. Sorry for messing it up and being unclear.